# Как отправить сообщение по таймеру Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, schedule

Недавно я начала писать бота, и теперь хочу добавить к нему автоматическое сообщение в 10:00 и 17:00.

Это мой код, вместо USER_ID я написала свой телеграмм ID для проверки:

```
from aiogram import executor
import time
from multiprocessing.context import Process
import schedule
from loader import dp, bot
import handlers
from set_bot_comands import set_default_commands

async def on_startup(dp):
    await set_default_commands(dp)

def send_message1():
    bot.send_message(USER_ID, 'TEXT')
 
schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(send_message1)

class ScheduleMessage():
    def try_send_schedule():
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
 
    def start_process():
        p1 = Process(target=ScheduleMessage.try_send_schedule, args=())
        p1.start()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScheduleMessage.start_process()
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup)
```

После запуска бота выбивает такую ошибку

```
c:\Users\ann\Documents\Python\BOT\Dennis_chooses_dinner\bot.py:22: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited
  bot.send_message(USER_ID, 'TEXT')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

А после завершения работы программы вот такую

```
Process Process-1:
Goodbye!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ann\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\ann\Documents\Python\BOT\Dennis_chooses_dinner\bot.py", line 31, in try_send_schedule
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: если ты ищешь решение для отложенных постов в канал, на сей час лучшее решение - telethon и его параметр метода send_message schedule

Comment: Просто await добавил бы, твоя проблема решилась бы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нашла такой способ решения. Существует асинхронная библиотека aioschedule, она работает для aiogram.

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule
    
@dp.message_handler()
async def choose_your_dinner():
    for user in set(the_users_without_dinner()):
        await bot.send_message(chat_id = user, text = "Хей не забудь 
        выбрать свой ужин сегодня", reply_markup = menu_garnish)

async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("17:45").do(choose_your_dinner)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
async def on_startup(dp): 
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(on_startup=on_startup)
```