# Отправка сообщений ботом в группе telegram в определенный промежуток времени

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Всем добрый день. Пишу своего первого бота на Python и столкнулась с проблемой реализации одной функции бота, прошерстив гугл не нашла похожих ситуаций у других пользователей. Задача стоит такая:  бот должен в группе отправлять определенное сообщение в ответ на сообщение любого участника группы, которое написано в промежутке с 21:00 до 9:00.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно это реализовать, и можно ли это реализовать через schedule и time?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1327154/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82-python-aiogram

Comment: Это для aiogram'a

Comment: Можно проверять время сообщения через `datetime.now()` или `message.date` https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message. Если время сообщения попадает в нужный интервал - `bot.reply_to()`