# Не могу подружить aiogram и aioschedule

Tags: python, aiogram, schedule

Задача чтобы бот писал сообщения раз в месяц, но я пытаюсь заставить его для начала отправлять сообщения каждые две секунды.

Код такой:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def give_counter():
    users = await db.all_users()
    for user in users:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=int(user),
                               text=f'Я напоминаю, пора подавать показатели счетчиков.',
                               reply_markup=kb.give_count())`


async def scheduler():
aioschedule.every(2).seconds.do(give_counter)
while True:
    await aioschedule.run_pending()

async def on_startup(_):
   await db.connect()
   await asyncio.create_task(scheduler())
```

Ошибка:

```
      raise TypeError("Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.")
TypeError: Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Job.run' was never awaited
```

Comment: сообщение об ошибке указывает, что вы пытаетесь передать корутину(асинхронную функцию) в функцию, которая не поддерживает асинхронные функции

Comment: `aioschedule.every(2).seconds.do(give_counter)` - обвчная функция, а не асинхронная

Comment: @SeniorPomidor но библиотека aioschedule асинхронная, нет?

Нашел ответ здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1327154/Как-отправить-сообщение-по-таймеру-aiogram
пытаюсь воспроизвести, не выходит

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, нет, не заработало

Comment: потому что не явно ожидаете выполнения функции give_counter, когда вы добавляете ее в планировщик.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor нет, TypeError('Passing coroutines is forbidden, use tasks explicitly.

RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: последняя попытка и я иду спать https://pastebin.com/H4UZHLAH

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может заключаться в том что, aioschedule не обновлялся уже 5 лет, и он не совместим с python 3.10 и более поздними версиями.
Попробуйте установить вот этот форк https://github.com/AleksHeller/python-aioschedule

`pip install https://github.com/AleksHeller/python-aioschedule/archive/master.zip`

Answer (score 0):

вот решение, проблема заключалась в том, что в новой версии Python поменяли работу async. 2 способа решения внизу
https://progr.interplanety.org/ustranenie-oshibki-passing-coroutines-is-forbidden-use-tasks-explicitly-pri-ispolzovanii-aioschedule-v-python-3-11/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)